# Export glb animation WITH shadows

Tags: shadows

How do you export a glb with shadows? Using Cycles with GPU Compute. Goal is a webAR animation. I have tried so many combinations. I have even done a test of simple animation of blocks on a plane and nothing is casting or receiving shadows in the gLTF viewer.

Comment: Shadows are calculated in Blender by the render engine according to the objects and lights in the scene. If the gLTF viewer cannot render these things, they will not appear no matter what you do in Blender. Or you have to bake textures complete with lighting and shadows, but for that I would recommend watching dedicated tutorials on that topic to learn about it or search for "texture bake" or "baking" on this site. But the questions and answers here usually focus on solving specific problems, we are not providing full tutorials here so you might want to search elsewhere, too.

Comment: Hi, @GordonBrinkmann  .. I  know your comment may seem  very obvious to those of us with more experience of how stuff works, , but IMO it could still be pretty much cut-and-pasted into an acceptable answer to an acceptable question, ticked, and  become part of the archive.

Comment: @RobinBetts Well, I've once seen tutorials on texture baking, never use it for myself so I only know _that_ you can bake textures with shading, but no in-depth knowledge _how_ to do that best. So I could only link to other answers here (if I knew which give best advice) resulting in suggesting to close this question as duplicate or give links to some Youtube tutorials which I deem to be a low quality answer (and first I would have to search for tutorials and watch them to see if they are good, not that I could really evaluate that).

Comment: Thanks for your time. It looks like I was expecting too much. I revised the design and animation and will be using a shadow catcher. Thanks for your input.